# MYSQL select-query with complicated logic

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data about agents voting for different options at different times:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| option     | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| agent      | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date       | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I'd like to output all rows where at least *a* agents voted at least at *t* dates for one of at most *o* options.

So, assume, e.g., *a*=2, *t*=3, *o*=1. Then I want to output only those rows which sum up to (count) >= 3*2 and in which for at least 3 different dates are votings for one of at most 1 options of 2 different agents. E.g.:

The select command I'm looking for should output from:

```
+--------+-------+------+
| option | agent | date |
+--------+-------+------+
|  opt1  |   a   |   1  |
|  opt1  |   a   |   2  |
|  opt1  |   a   |   3  |
|  opt2  |   b   |   1  |
|  opt2  |   b   |   2  |
|  opt2  |   b   |   3  |
|  opt1  |   c   |   1  |
|  opt1  |   c   |   2  |
|  opt1  |   c   |   3  |
+--------+-------+------+
```

Only the rows of agent a and c:

```
+--------+-------+------+
|  opt1  |   a   |   1  |
|  opt1  |   a   |   2  |
|  opt1  |   a   |   3  |
|  opt2  |   b   |   1  |
|  opt1  |   c   |   1  |
|  opt1  |   c   |   2  |
|  opt1  |   c   |   3  |
+--------+-------+------+
```

Is there a way to do so or do I have to run through a set of combinations via a script (PHP)? Thanks a lot, Christian

Comment: I am somewhat confused by your requirements. Can you put a few more stages to your description. I can't see why agent b is in the final results once, when all 3 of their entries seem the same, or is that only there as a typo?

Comment: This is a confusion point for me: "voted at least at t dates for one of at most o options." is the 0 a typo?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @Kickstart: I'm very sorry - the row with agent b in the output is incorrect. ad Len_D: "o" stands for the number of options. Actually, I could simplify the logic behind the query I need as follows: Show all rows so that for _a*t_ rows there are agents _A1,...,Aa_, dates _T1,...,Tt_ and options _O1,...,Oo_ such that each of the agents opts for each date for one out of _O1,...,Oo_ options. ...

Comment: ad Kickstart and @Len_D:

In a PHP-script I would run through all subsets of the set of dates with exactly _t_ elements and would output all those subsets, where the intersection of all agents opting at some date in the subset has at least _a_ elements and where the union of options opted for by exactly _a_ agents has at most _o_ elements. But the problem is that this procedure is quite time consuming and with more than 2500 dates impossible to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Think you will need a couple of sub queries. One to get all the options / agents with at least as many dates as required, and then using that as the source for another query to find the number of options with at least the required number of agents. Then join the results of that back against your table to get the details for those options.

```
SELECT sometable.`option`, sometable.agent, sometable.date
FROM
(
    SELECT `option`, COUNT(DISTINCT agent) as distinct_agents
    FROM
    (
        SELECT `option`, agent, COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS distinct_dates 
        FROM sometable
        GROUP BY `option`, agent
        HAVING distinct_dates >= 3
    ) sub0
    GROUP BY `option`
    HAVING distinct_agents >=2
) sub1
INNER JOIN sometable
ON sub1.`option` = sometable.`option`
```

SQL fiddle for it:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e357/2